# SparkContext class not found error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to run scala code on spark using intellij.

Scala Code

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("anything").setMaster("localhost"))
    println("Hello World!")
  } 
}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.vocp</groupId>
<artifactId>SparkScalaConnect</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkContext
at WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:9)
at WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I have tried to run the same code on **Scala-IDE** and it runs **FINE**. I see the problem might be in intellij editor.

Stuck in this problem for a long time. Any advice would be beneficial.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**- I am running the code on 1.7 JAVA Oracle and 2.10.5 scala SDK.

Comment: Does the spark-core included in project module settings in list of libraries?

Comment: scala-core_2.10 is present in the external libraries in the project. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: https://github.com/hammadhaleem/SparkDemo/blob/master/DataReader.scala#L17  local => local[8] this would solve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this change scope for spark dependencies from `provided` to `compile`

[issue](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/IntelliJ-Runtime-error-tt11383.html#a11384)

Comment: Changed all the scope of dependencies and everything worked fine.